# Cannot modify country in paypal

Tags: html, paypal, payment

I'm implementing a paypal payment in my website but the country is not changing when I'm checking out. Please see my code below:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="Shipping Address">
        <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="Building name and office number">


        <input type="hidden" name="city" value="Tokyo">
        <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="2024">
        <input type="hidden" name="country" value="JP">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating hosted button then the variables that you want to be set need to set on PayPal hosted button page.

You can modify your hosted button and try adding this. Links for your reference:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buy_now_step_1/
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/